# Square Diagonal Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Here is my problem.

Write a Java program that creates a diagonal through a square. For example, a 3X3 square should look as follows:

100

010

001

As of right now my out put is

000

000

000

So I have the basics of looping the array down. unfortunately trying to loop an integer from 0,0 to 1,1 to 2,2 has eluded me.

so far my code looks like:

```
static void printDiagonalInSquare(int input){

    final int d; //length of rows and columns
        d = input;
    
    
      int[][] array=new int[d][d]; //length and heigth of array
      
        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < d; rowIndex++) { 
           if (array[rowIndex] != null){
            for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < d; colIndex++){
                System.out.print(array[rowIndex][colIndex]);
                
            }
               System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

So ideally I can input any integer and it will create a 2d matrix with a 1 traveling down the square in a diagonal.

Comment: Basically you want a one wherever the row index is the same as the column index.

Comment: Yes that is the exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Well, you already have the nested loops, you just need to compare `rowIndex` and `colIndex` and change the value of `array[rowIndex][colIndex]` when they match...

Comment: I'm still  fairly new to coding so I'm not quite sure how that code would look.

Comment: Try something like https://rextester.com/KDU27893

Comment: That works perfect! can you explain to me how that print statement works?
System.out.print(rowIndex == colIndex ? 1 : 0);

Comment: That's a ternary operator. Google "Java ternary operator" and you will find lots of resources explaining how it works.

Comment: Got it Thanks a lot Nick! Found a resource to explain it.

Comment: @Griffon of course you can keep on a more intuitive code just making the condition above explicit, i.e. after the second `for` you can simply add: `if (rowIndex == colIndex) array[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1;` before printing the matrix value. This only to say that you don't necessarily need the ternary operator to complete your task. Anyway ternary operator is widely used, so it's good to get used to it too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare rowIndex and colIndex and change the value of array[rowIndex][colIndex] when they match

When rowIndex is equal to colIndex if true 1 if false 0

System.out.print(rowIndex == colIndex ? 1 : 0);

Google "Java ternary operator" To find lots of resources